# In what order are expressions in an `if` condition evaluated?

Tags: c++, if-statement, evaluation

Is the following a safe code?

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v = buildVector();
  if (v.size() > 2 && v[1]==2)
  {
     doThis();  
  } else
  {
     doThat();  
  }
}
```

or should do I rather do

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v = buildVector();
  if (v.size() > 2)
  {
     if (v[1] == 2)
     {
        doThis();
     } else
     {
        doThat();
     }
  } else
  {
     doThat();
  }
}
```

My fear is that it would try to evaluate `v[1] == 2` before `v.size() > 2` and yield to a segmentation fault or something. How about a similar situation using logical OR?

Will C++ always evaluate the expressions in a `if` condition in the order provided and stop as soon as it has enough information to know if it is `true` or `false`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation I suggest you read a book on C++ first.

Comment: It is a duplicate indeed. From what I get, the first code is safe. Thank you. Thanks also for the link to wiki > short-circuit evaluation.